# json_decode() returns different answer

Tags: php, json, geturl

I need to check if the user is logged in through json api.
The json api URL must be:
http://www.[targetdomain].com/api/logged?s_email=MY_EMAIL
and if the specified email is logged in the response is

```
{ 'user': 'true' }
```

If the user is not logged in, the response is

```
{ 'user': 'false' }
```

My PHP code to the destination is:

```
<?php
$s_email = 'myemail@email.com';
$ez_get="http://www.[targetdomain].com/api/logged?s_email=".$s_email."";
$raw = file_get_contents($ez_get);
$objs = str_replace("'", "\"", $raw);
$obj = json_decode($objs);

echo $obj->{"user"};
?>

<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="<?php echo $ez_get; ?>" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The user is logged in. 
If I check the api in my browser typing the full URL the api response is true.

From php part I get the echo false.
In iFrame the result is true.

What am I doing wrong?
I was digging through stackoverflow and it seems it is a matter of header but CURL is not activated on my server.
Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to http://www.[targetdomain].com/api/logged? It is not clear from the question but perhaps it relies on cookies. So here is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have access to both servers. I will investigate and I will get back to you.

Comment: The targetdomain is a symfony platform and it has a session controller for that...
The solution was a different module that compares an API key instead of login status. If somebody else will get a new solution I will be more than happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was written to ask a more complex query including api code so it's a back / forth response.